# Highchart speedometer take input from csv

Tags: csv, highcharts

I am trying to read the data from `csv` and display it as a input to Speedometer but I am unable to get the chart. Please tell me where i am going wrong.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Speedometer'
        },
        pane: {
            startAngle: -150,
            endAngle: 150,
            background: [{
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFF'],
                        [1, '#333']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '109%'
            }, {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#333'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                outerRadius: '107%'
            }, {
                // default background
            }, {
                backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '105%',
                innerRadius: '103%'
            }]
        },
        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,

            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 1,
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#666',

            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 2,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#666',
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'km/h'
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 120,
                color: '#55BF3B' // green
            }, {
                from: 120,
                to: 160,
                color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
            }, {
                from: 160,
                to: 200,
                color: '#DF5353' // red
            }]        
        },  
        series: []
    };               
    $.get('data.csv', function(data) {              
        var series = {
            data: [],
            name: 'Speed',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            }
        };

        series.data.push(parseFloat(data));
        options.series.push(series);
        alert("data "+options.series);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);                      
    });
});
```

and the csv file is simple
data.csv has only one value 30.
or incase it is

```
t1,30
t2,40
t3,60
```

how do i display 3 corresponding speedometers with respective speed.
Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case data your data (from ajax) is a single string, but you need to split elements and then choose which should be parsed to integer (parseFloat).